# Opening .odt files on webpage using html

Tags: javascript, html, odt

I'm currently working on web page and trying to open .odt files by using html and javascript. The .odt files are stored in my computer and I want to print them in my web page. Plus, is it possible to store each sentences(which are in .odt file) in variables one by one? My goal is to open .odt file on web page, modify the contents of .odt file, and then save the .odt file back to my computer.

sorry that my question is abstract but I just started. There's not much related information on google please help

Comment: take a look at https://pandoc.org/

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with just HTML and JS.  You need a server side language or tool.  There are several questions about how to modify an ODT file here on StackOverflow, but they're server side language specific (C, python, etc)